# Can Windows Virtual PC run a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm running [Windows Virtual PC (RC)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4c3a0944-a2e6-4f01-9c57-5b55885875cc) on a Windows 7 (RTM) 64-bit host. When I create a new virtual machine and try to install 64-bit Windows 7 on that VM, I get "this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode."

Is there a way to create 64-bit virtual machines?

Comment: "Windows Virtual PC" is the product name, so that's why I used that as the tag.

Comment: I found this odd myself, especially as there is separate x86 and x64 installers...

Comment: After I asked this question, a duplicate was added to superuser via migration from serverfault. http://superuser.com/questions/28043/64-bit-guest-oss-virtual-pc-rc-on-windows-7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Windows Virtual PC does not support 64-bit guests. You may want to look into [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/). You may also want to see the answers to the [similar question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/52189/64-bit-guest-oss-virtual-pc-rc-on-windows-7).

Comment: VirtualBox website says "VirtualBox is a general-purpose full virtualizer for x86 hardware" and makes no claim for (Intel) x64 architecture

Comment: @Rowland, do some research: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBox_vs_Others

Comment: @John T that only says "64 host OS support" - it doesn't specify *which* 64 bit architecture it supports (x64 or ia64, etc.)

Comment: @Rowland, you aren't even looking for the right thing. A VM is considered a guest, not a host.