# Virtual PC says I cannot virtualize 64-bit even though VT is on

Tags: virtual-machine, 64-bit, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am having a tough time with my ASUS motherboard's BIOS at the moment, saying that Intel's Virtualisation Technology is on, even though Virtual PC is saying I cannot use a 64-bit ISO containing Windows 7 Home Premium to install onto the virtual machine.

I return to the BIOS on various occasions, even stopped overclocking my processor, graphics card and my RAM to see if that worked but to no avail not allowing me to install a 64-bit version. I refuse to use 32-bit since it is essentially against EULA to use the same serial key on a system that is not the same operating system.

If it helps to answer my question, my CPU is an Intel i5-3570K overclocked to 4.5GHz, with VT enabled, RAM (2x4GB, 1333MHz) overclocked to 1648MHz and an overclocked NVIDIA GTX 670. Not sure if that information is essential to answering my issue but I sure hope it is no coincidence.

And in case you were wondering why I am using Virtual PC on a gaming rig is because I am developing my own games but would like to do so using Virtual PC for obvious reasons. Not only does it annoy me that 64-bit won't install, I've even attempted to mount the ISO onto an external application but that didn't seem to help.

Another thing to point out is the fact that for some reason, even though VT is on, it states the error "Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode."

It also asks me to *Repair my Computer*, even though there is nothing wrong with it, and points to the file `\windows\system32\boot\winload.exe` and the error code `0xc000035a`

Let me know what you think I should do to solve this issue, please. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual PC cannot run 64-bit guests**. It's very old (the last version was released in 2011) and doesn't even support other OSes properly

> Lastly, while 64-bit host support was introduced with Virtual PC 2007, **no release has been able to virtualize a 64-bit guest**; Microsoft has thus far reserved this functionality for Hyper-V, which runs only on 64-bit (x64) editions of Windows Server 2008.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Supported_host_and_guest_operating_systems

You should use other hypervisors such as VirtualBox, VMWare or MS Hyper-V which are all much more powerful and have more features than Virtual PC

See also

- [Is it possible to have 64 bit guest OSes run in Virtual PC RC on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/28043/241386)
- [MS Virtual PC will not Start a 64 bit Guest](https://superuser.com/q/749386/241386)