# MS Virtual PC will not Start a 64 bit Guest

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, 64-bit, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 7, 64 bit.  I would like to install Windows 8.1, 64 bit, and have been attempting to use the MS Virtual PC hypervisor.

I attached the Windows ISO as the CD drive. It does try to boot Windows ISO, but I get the error:

- `This 64 bit application couldnt load becuase your PC doesn't have a 64 bit processor... error code is 0x000035a`
- file is \windows\system32\boot\winload.exe .

I know my pc has a 64 bit processor and I know I went into the BIOS and enabled virtualization.

Have I configured the virtual machine in Virtual PC incorrectly and set it to have a 32 bit processor without realizing it?

Or is there another step I am missing to make this work as intended?

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit version of Windows?

Comment: Yes I am running 64 bit windows 7 on the pc I am trying to run the vm on

Comment: Downloaded virtual box and appears to be working. Installing windows now. Thanks.

Comment: I have moved my answer to an answer below, could you mark your question answered that solution worked for you.

Comment: This is a related question that might be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/144539/can-i-install-windows-7-64-bit-on-virtualbox-running-on-a-windows-7-32-bit-os visualization technology must be supported to do this with Virtual Box at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying run a 64 bit Windows 8, with a 32 bit version of Virtual PC.

Try downloading the 64 bit version of Virtualbox.

You might need to uninstall Virtual PC.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualPC **doesn't support 64Bit guests** only 32Bit guests! You need 3rd party tools like Hyper-V, VirtualBox or VMware (Player, Workstation)