# Windows Virtual PC says CPU is not compatible with x64 mode, but Virtual PC is run in a 64 bits OS system

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install a WindowsXP 64 bits in Windows Virtual PC. Windows Virtual PC complains:

> Attempting to load an x64 operating system, however this CPU is not
>   compatible with x64 mode. Please install a 32-bit x86 operating
>   system.

But the whole thing is running under a Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits. How can this be? What coult it be the problem?

Comment: Why using old Virtual PC? Try VirtualBox.

Comment: because it was there, but I guess I will have no other choice than to download a new one according to what the answer says

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Windows Virtual PC run a 64-bit OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/28006/can-windows-virtual-pc-run-a-64-bit-os) and [Is it possible to have 64 bit guest OSes run in Virtual PC RC on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/28043/is-it-possible-to-have-64-bit-guest-oses-run-in-virtual-pc-rc-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows Virtual PC does not support 64 bit guests.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Table_of_supported_operating_systems) chart. Note the complete absence of any 64-bit guest column. This hypervisor is emulation based, so you are stuck with whatever software they use to emulate the hardware/processor. If the emulator only emulates a 32 bit processor, you will only be able to use 32 bit OS and applications. Use another hypervisor that supports 64 bit guests, such as Oracle Virtual Box or VMware Player.